# Python Print overlapping with input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, python-multithreading

I am creating server and in console it displays some info and the problem is the user/admin is typing in that console threads are still printing input to console and then it's hard to type and even more then command is complex.

Code to show that problem:

```
import threading
import random
import time

def some_process():  # simulation of server that print some info in background
    for i in range(50)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        print("Some program output")

thread = threading.Thread(target=some_process)
thread.start()

while True:
    shell = input("> ")
    # rest of shell like "help", "exit" and some things like that
```

Output:

```
> connect localhoSome program output
st 4665 SSL=TrSome program output
ue
```

What I exept:

```
Some program output
Some program output
> connect localhost 4665 SSL=True  # That line move then something print.
```

And if this possible, I am looking for most cross-platform solution. (Most looking for windows solution but need be linux too)

Comment: You are doing to things simultaneously

Comment: Yes, because then one thread is accpeting request to server and other is menaging database, code here is example of problem.

Comment: If you use the same console, at the same time, to display output from your program and to accept input from the user, then you have to use something like Curses to multiplex the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to manipulate the cursor location. All output has to be stored in a list that will be printed at each update.

ANSI commands

- `\033[s` store current cursor location
- `\033[u` reset cursor location
- `\33[2K` erase current line
- `[NA` move cursor N lines up
- `[2J` clear the terminal

`chr(27)` is escape

```
import threading
import random
import time

output_lines = []

def print_above(message):
    global output_lines
    output_lines.append(message)
    
    for i, line in enumerate(reversed(output_lines)):
        print(f"\033[s{chr(27)}[{i+1}A\33[2K\r{line}\033[u", end="")

def some_process():  # simulation of server that print some info in background
    for i in range(12):
        time.sleep(0.1*random.randint(5, 10))
        print_above(f"Thread output {12-i}")

thread = threading.Thread(target=some_process)
thread.start()

print(chr(27) + "[2J") # clearing the terminal
while True:
    shell = input("> ")
    print_above(f"shell {shell}")
```

Sample output

```
Thread output 12
Thread output 11
Thread output 10
Thread output 9
shell 123
Thread output 8
Thread output 7
Thread output 6
Thread output 5
Thread output 4
Thread output 3
Thread output 2
Thread output 1
> 987654321
```

This is not a perfect solution as there are potentially many edge cases it will not handle well and it might not work on all terminals. It may also need to be complemented to handle threading really well.